How to get equation from Python statsmodels GAM?
I am fitting a mulit-variate non-linear equation using statsmodel.GLMGam(). The fitted model gives me a summary with coefficients for all B-spline components. How can I make sense of these coefficients, i.e. what is the formula / equation of the fitted model and what is the relationship between the independent and dependent variables?
My sample code is as below:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.gam.api import GLMGam, BSplines

np.random.seed(10)

# Define dataset
n = 500
x1 = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=2*np.pi, size=(n,))
x2 = np.random.uniform(low=5.0, high=30.0, size=(n,))
x3 = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=20.0, size=(n,))
y = 10*np.abs(np.sin(x1)) - x2 + 500 + np.random.uniform(size=y.shape)

df_data = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((x1.shape[0], 4)), columns={"x1", "x2", "x3", "y"})
df_data["x1"] = x1
df_data["x2"] = x2
df_data["x3"] = x3
df_data["y"] = y

# Fit model
bs = BSplines(df_data[['x1', "x2", "x3"]], df=[10,10,10], degree=[3,3,3])
gam_model = GLMGam.from_formula('y ~ 1', data=df_data, smoother=bs)
res_gam_model = gam_model.fit()
display(res_gam_model.summary())

The summary table shows coefficients as follows:
| variable | coef | std err | z | P>z | [0.025 | 0.975] |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
|Intercept|495.2222|0.340|1455.777|0.000|494.556|495.889|
|x1_s0|4.0433|0.408|9.905|0.000|3.243|4.843|
|x1_s1|7.7686|0.261|29.808|0.000|7.258|8.279|
|x1_s2|13.6046|0.318|42.783|0.000|12.981|14.228|
|...|...|...|...|...|...|...|

Technically I can use predict() or get_prediction() as a black box to get the predicted values. But to understand how the variables affect another, I need to visualize the plots and trends of the independent variables.

There is no simple formula for the spline basis functions, see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline To see the effect of the spline term use partial_values and plot_partial methods or use predict setting all other slope variables (in exog) to zero.
